# React include multiple props via variable for children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Need to pass down a set of functions to a couple of child components.
Anyway to do so along the lines of this:

```
render(){

    var commonFs = {
        function1={this.function1},
        function2={this.function2},
        function3={this.function3},
        function4={this.function4},
        function4={this.function5},
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <ChildA {commonFs} functionA={this.functionA} />
            <ChildB {commonFs} functionB={this.functionB} />
            <ChildC {commonFs} functionC={this.functionC} />
            <ChildD {commonFs} functionD={this.functionD} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do this

```
render(){

    var commonFs = {
        function1: this.function1,
        function2: this.function2,
        function3: this.function3,
        function4: this.function4,
        function5: this.function5,
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <ChildA {...commonFs} functionA={this.functionA} />
            <ChildB {...commonFs} functionB={this.functionB} />
            <ChildC {...commonFs} functionC={this.functionC} />
            <ChildD {...commonFs} functionD={this.functionD} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, spreading props into components can lead to code which is hard to follow if abused.

Comment: The syntax `function1: {this.function1}` is incorrect. It will not work

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){

    var commonFs = {
        function1: this.function1,
        function2: this.function2,
        function3: this.function3,
        function4: this.function4,
        function4: this.function5
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <ChildA commonFs={commonFs} functionA={this.functionA} />
            <ChildB commonFs={commonFs} functionB={this.functionB} />
            <ChildC commonFs={commonFs} functionC={this.functionC} />
            <ChildD commonFs={commonFs} functionD={this.functionD} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then inside the child, you can reference the common functions with `this.props.commonFs.function1` etc...

Comment: Thanks! Though this results in `functionA|B|C|D` not being in the same 'scope' as the others.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: `{ keyName1=value1, keyName2=value2 }` is the invalid syntax.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. However the part about `commonFs={commonFs}` is still correct. So @House3272 can use this approach, if they want.